# Migrate AmazonWebServiceClient to ApiGatewayAsyncClient in aws-sdk-java-v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-sdk-java

I'm currently using an **AWS java client to request a gateway API**.

The actual code relies on <s>"aws-sdk-java"</s> and I want to migrate the more modern version **"aws-sdk-java-v2"**.
The client would then benefit from a non blocking I/O API. Turns out, migrating from v1 to v2 is not straightforward (at least for me).
I would gladly appreciate some guidance on this.

More specifically I need to stop extending the <s>`com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient`</s> class for the more modern **`software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.ApiGatewayAsyncClient`** class.

**There are several parts of the code I can't figure out to properly migrate:**

- How to provide correct signer `software.amazon.awssdk.core.signer.Signer` and/or `software.amazon.awssdk.core.signer.AsyncSigner` ?
- How to provide response and error handler ?
- Is method `getGatewayResponse` of `client` the right method to call the api in an asynchronous manner ?

The original code is based on [How to call AWS API Gateway From the Java code ?](https://inspeerity.com/blog/how-to-call-aws-api-gateway-from-the-java-code/)

```java
package com.piotrfilipowicz.aws;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.DefaultRequest;
import com.amazonaws.RequestConfig;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.http.ExecutionContext;
import com.amazonaws.http.HttpMethodName;
import com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler;
import com.amazonaws.http.JsonResponseHandler;
import com.amazonaws.internal.AmazonWebServiceRequestAdapter;
import com.amazonaws.internal.auth.DefaultSignerProvider;
import com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonOperationMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredPlainJsonFactory;
import com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller;
import com.amazonaws.transform.JsonUnmarshallerContext;
import com.amazonaws.transform.Unmarshaller;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JsonApiGatewayCaller extends AmazonWebServiceClient {
    private static final String API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "execute-api";

    private final AWSCredentialsProvider credentials;
    private final String apiKey;
    private final AWS4Signer signer;

    private final JsonResponseHandler<ApiGatewayResponse> responseHandler;
    private final JsonErrorResponseHandler errorResponseHandler;

    public JsonApiGatewayCaller(String accessKey, String secretAccessKey, String apiKey, String region, URI endpoint) {

        super(new ClientConfiguration());

        this.credentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey));
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;

        this.signer = new AWS4Signer();
        this.signer.setServiceName(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
        this.signer.setRegionName(region);

        final JsonOperationMetadata metadata = new JsonOperationMetadata().withHasStreamingSuccessResponse(false).withPayloadJson(false);
        final Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext> responseUnmarshaller = in -> new ApiGatewayResponse(in.getHttpResponse());
        this.responseHandler = SdkStructuredPlainJsonFactory.SDK_JSON_FACTORY.createResponseHandler(metadata, responseUnmarshaller);

        JsonErrorUnmarshaller defaultErrorUnmarshaller = new JsonErrorUnmarshaller(ApiGatewayException.class, null) {
            @Override
            public AmazonServiceException unmarshall(JsonNode jsonContent) throws Exception {
                return new ApiGatewayException(jsonContent.toString());
            }
        };

        this.errorResponseHandler = SdkStructuredPlainJsonFactory.SDK_JSON_FACTORY.createErrorResponseHandler(
                Collections.singletonList(defaultErrorUnmarshaller), null);
    }

    public ApiGatewayResponse execute(HttpMethodName method, String resourcePath, InputStream content) {
        final ExecutionContext executionContext = createExecutionContext();

        DefaultRequest request = prepareRequest(method, resourcePath, content);

        RequestConfig requestConfig = new AmazonWebServiceRequestAdapter(request.getOriginalRequest());

        return this.client.execute(request, responseHandler, errorResponseHandler, executionContext, requestConfig).getAwsResponse();
    }

    private DefaultRequest prepareRequest(HttpMethodName method, String resourcePath, InputStream content) {
        DefaultRequest request = new DefaultRequest(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
        request.setHttpMethod(method);
        request.setContent(content);
        request.setEndpoint(this.endpoint);
        request.setResourcePath(resourcePath);
        request.setHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("Content-type", "application/json"));
        return request;
    }

    private ExecutionContext createExecutionContext() {
        final ExecutionContext executionContext = ExecutionContext.builder().withSignerProvider(
                new DefaultSignerProvider(this, signer)).build();
        executionContext.setCredentialsProvider(credentials);
        return executionContext;
    }

}
```

My migrated code looks like that so far

```java
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientAsyncConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientOverrideConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.SdkAdvancedClientOption;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.signer.AsyncSigner;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.model.GetGatewayResponseRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.async.SdkAsyncHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.ApiGatewayAsyncClient;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AsyncGatewayClient extends ApiGatewayAsyncClient {

    public class AwsApiCredentialsProvider implements AwsCredentialsProvider {
        private final String accessKey;
        private final String secretAccessKey;

        public AwsApiCredentialsProvider(String accessKey, String secretAccessKey) {
            this.accessKey = accessKey;
            this.secretAccessKey = secretAccessKey;
        }

        @Override
        public AwsCredentials resolveCredentials() {
            return AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
        }
    }

    public final static SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient.builder().build();

    public AsyncGatewayClient(
       String accessKey, String secretAccessKey, String endPointString, String regionUid
    ) {
        AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AwsApiCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
        Region region = Region.of(regionUid);

        URI endPointUri;
        try {
            endPointUri = new URI(endPointString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new ConfigException.Missing("Endpoint is not a valid URI: " + endPointString);
        }

        ClientAsyncConfiguration overrideAsyncConfig = ClientAsyncConfiguration.builder()
                .advancedOptions(new SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption(AsyncSigner.class), )
                .build();
        ClientOverrideConfiguration overrideConfig = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                .advancedOptions(SdkAdvancedClientOption.SIGNER, )
                .build();

        ApiGatewayAsyncClient client = ApiGatewayAsyncClient.builder()
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .endpointOverride(endpoint)
                .overrideConfiguration(overrideConfig)
                .asyncConfiguration(overrideAsyncConfig)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .region(region)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this when trying to do exactly the same thing and migrate from the example given on [How to call aws api gateway from the java code](https://inspeerity.com/blog/how-to-call-aws-api-gateway-from-the-java-code) to something that used v2 of the sdk.  I dont know if you got it working in the end but I thought I'd share my solution for others that might come looking :)

Rather than try and recreate things as they were I've ended up with something a lot simpler which seems to work

```
    // get creds (Could use the defaultCredentialsProvider)
    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName(<MY_PROFILE>).build();
    AwsCredentials credentials = credentialsProvider.resolveCredentials();

    // Build query params 
    List<NameValuePair> queryParams = new ArrayList<>();
    queryParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "test"));
    queryParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "1234"));

    // create URI with params
    URI uri = new URIBuilder(<THE URL>)
            .addParameters(queryParams)
            .build();

    // create the request
    final SdkHttpFullRequest request = SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
            .method(SdkHttpMethod.GET)
            .uri(uri)
            .build();

    //Sign it...
    Aws4Signer signer = Aws4Signer.create();
    Aws4SignerParams signerParams = Aws4SignerParams.builder()
            .signingRegion(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .awsCredentials(credentials)
            .signingName("execute-api")
            .build();
    SdkHttpFullRequest signedRequest = signer.sign(request, signerParams);

    // create httpClient - set timeout and proxy config on this if necessary
    SdkHttpClient httpClient =  ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();

    // Create executable request
    HttpExecuteRequest executeRequest = HttpExecuteRequest.builder().request(signedRequest).build();
    ExecutableHttpRequest executableHttpRequest = httpClient.prepareRequest(executeRequest);

    // Execute the request
    HttpExecuteResponse res = executableHttpRequest.call();

    // get response 
    AbortableInputStream abortableInputStream = res.responseBody().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No Response Body found"));
```